# Does the metric of a homogeneous compact metric space lift to a metric on its group of isometries?

Tags: metric-spaces, lie-groups, compactness, topological-groups

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $Iso(X)$ be its group of isometries, and assume further that the action of $Iso(X)$ on $X$ is transitive. If we take the stabilizer $G_x$ of any element $x \in X$, we have that $X$ can be identified with $Iso(X)/G_x$. Now, does the metric $d = d_X$ on $X$ lift to a metric on $Iso(X)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "lift"? In the case when $X$ is a Riemannian manifold and $G$ is a Lie group acting smoothly, I know the meaning of this term and the Riemannian metric indeed lifts (via a connection on the bundle $G_x\to G \to X$). For general metric spaces, you can equip $Isom(X)$ with the uniform metric coming from $X$, of course. You do not even need transitivity.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).